# Java socket file transfer thread fails but works when I debug

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, sockets

I don't know why my program works when I debug it and fails in normal execution.

I have setup a simple server to feed a file over a socket. When a client connects a thread is started to carry this task out BUT it fails. I get a 'Socket is closed' error.

This is for homework: 
I can't advance until I figure out why this is happening and just want a nudge in the right direction please.

To get it to work in debug I set the break point in the server class where it accepts client connections.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class File_Server {

    private static ServerSocket servsock;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // create socket
    try {
        servsock = new ServerSocket(4444);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Port already in use.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        try (Socket sock = servsock.accept()) {
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

            Thread t = new Thread(new CLIENTConnection(sock));

            t.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot accept connection.");
            }
        }
    }
}



public class CLIENTConnection implements Runnable {

    private Socket client;

    CLIENTConnection(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = null;         
            // sendfile
            File myFile = new File("studentData.txt");
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CLIENTConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
}



public class File_Client {

    private static long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private static int bytesRead;
    private static int current = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        int filesize = 60223861; // filesize temporary hardcoded

        try (Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444)) {
            System.out.println("Connecting...");

            // receive file
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("studentData-received.txt");
            try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {
                bytesRead = is.read();//.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                current = bytesRead;

                do {
                    bytesRead =
                            is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
                    if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                        current += bytesRead;
                    }
                } while (bytesRead > -1);

                bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
                bos.flush();
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Time taken " + (end - start) + " milliseconds");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to server.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the usual error of ignoring the result of read(). It returns the number of bytes actually read, or -1 at EOS. The way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

where 'count' is an int.

Comment: @MihaiDanila Nope, read() can only return zero *bytes* if you pass a zero length buffer or a count argument of zero, which would be a programming error.

Comment: I distinctly recall having to check for zero in the past, as I was sometimes getting zero back, especially with socket-bound streams. So I went in and double checked the `InputStream` javadoc, and sure enough `read(byte[], int, int)` may return zero bytes. You are also right, in that `read(byte[])` cannot.

Comment: Nevermind that either, upon reading the javadocs more closely, it seems zero is only returned in cases like the one you mentioned. This part surely confuses: "An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read, possibly zero.".

Comment: @MihaiDanila I've been doing Java network programming since 1997 and I have never had zero back. But then I've never specified a zero length buffer or count.

Comment: Then I must be confusing this with something else. I too used to work with streams back in 1997, but then I moved on to other things. :)

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your reply. I tried to add your amendment to my CLIENTConnection class and I still get the same result. I'm putting the `while` around `bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);`. What I find puzzling is using the same client code and the server code without threads works perfectly fine. I'm sure I'm placing the `while` incorrectly.

Comment: I rewrote my CLIENTConnection from scratch with the correct code to handle EOS and again it only transfers files successfully in debug mode. I'm don't understand why though :(

Comment: @chrisloughnane It isn't clear from what you say that you are now using exactly the code I posted. If you don't use the 'count' variable in both places as shown it won't work. The reason it works better in debug mode is that there are longer delays, so more data to read, so the reads are more likely to fill the buffer. Still not guaranteed, though.

Comment: @MihaiDanila Come off it. You've never used a stream since 1997?

Comment: @EJP thanks for clarifying the debug. I rewrote it again and have a working version. Thanks for your help. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20961/java-multi-thread-file-server-and-client

Comment: @EJP Please observe the relative lack of importance of whether I'm off by a couple of years, or whether the statement is made in absolute terms. If I happened to use streams yesterday after a long hiatus, I still may not have noticed the detail in the JavaDocs. What is thoroughly important is that the JDK 1.4 JavaDoc (the one that remained in memory from the days I coded directly with streams instead of `IOUtils`) did indicate that `read` can return zero even with a non-zero buffer size, albeit in a contradictory manner.

Comment: I deleted the first comment in order to make sure users who won't read through the whole list don't internalize that incorrect information.